# You are nothing like as critical as you used to be. Why not use ‘not’?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, prepositions

You are nothing like as critical as you used to be.

Why not say ‘You are not like as critical as you used to be’ ?

Answer (score 3):

Because it would be meaningless.

*You are not as critical as you used to be* is fine. But *not like* is not used the way you suggest.

*Nothing like* is an idiom, expressing an emphatic difference.

Comment: Is ‘Nothing like’ a noun?

Comment: @Y.zeng. No. In this context, it is syntactically interchangeable with _not_. In other contexts, it behaves as a preposition.